# Get A Path from a nested object tree

Tags: javascript, recursion, coffeescript

I am currently stuck with a problem that when I started out seemed not to hard to solve for me, but i am stuck for a couple of hours now, so here we go:

Given this array of objects:

```
groups = [
  {
    name: 'Custard apple',
    slug: 'custard-apple',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Vanilla',
        slug: 'vanilla',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Strawberry',
            slug: 'strawberry',
            children: []
          }, {
            name: 'Pineapple',
            slug: 'pineapple',
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'Chocolate',
        slug: 'chocolate',
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Raspberry',
    slug: 'raspberry',
    children: []
  }, {
    name: 'Lemon',
    slug: 'lemon',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Orange',
        slug: 'orange',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Coconut',
            slug: 'coconut',
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'Almond',
        slug: 'almond',
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I am trying to find a function that gives me the path to an object with the help of a given `slug`:

```
var find_path = function(groups, slug) { /* looking for a solution to this */ };
result = find_path(groups, 'pineapple'); 

console.log(result);
// [{ name: 'Custard Apple', slug: 'custard-apple' }, { name: 'Vanilla', slug: 'vanilla'}, { name: 'Pineapple', slug: 'pinapple' }]

// another example
result = find_path(groups, 'lemon');
console.log(result);
// [{ name: 'Lemon', slug: 'lemon' }]
```

I tried several recursive methods in which I tried to save the path along the function calls, but I usually ended up with duplicates/not the desired result in general. I mainly revolved around a recursive lookup combined with (failed) attempts to save the path took along the way.

So, is there a recursive method to solve this problem? Or am I thinking too complicated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're dealing with a tree so recursion is a natural solution. A simple depth-first search (look at the current node then look at its children) is probably the easiest solution. Something like this:

```
slice = (o, properties...) ->
    ret = { }
    ret[p] = o[p] for p in properties
    ret

find_path = (a, slug) ->
    for o in a
        # Bail out now if this is what we're looking for.
        if(o.slug == slug)
            return [ slice(o, 'name', 'slug') ]
        # Scan the children if not.
        if(sub = find_path(o.children, slug))
            return [ slice(o, 'name', 'slug') ].concat(sub)
    # Explicitly return `undefined` to make sure the caller
    # gets The Right Thing back.
    return
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3FNZy/

Each step in the recursion gives you nothing or the path from the current node to the one you're looking for. Then unwinding the recursion builds the path through the [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) calls. Granted, there is a fair bit of array copying going on here but that's not worth worrying about for small data sets like this (and if you have more data then you'd want to switch to some sort of indexed structure).

The `slice` function is just there to make the "copy `e` but not `e.children`" logic a bit more readable; unfortunately you can't use a compound structure like `{ x.a, x.b } = obj` in a [destructured assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) so a `slice` function is about as good as you're going to get (you *can* say `{a,b} = obj` but you can't add the extra level of nesting to get an object slice).

Comment: Thanks :) In retrospect, this should probably been more obvious to me.